# Firebase functions failed to deploy

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting the following error whenever I deploy my firebase functions

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in D:\Proyectos\socialapp-functions\functions\node_modules\firebase\package.json
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:285:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:508:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:450:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:490:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Proyectos\socialapp-functions\functions\index.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
```

My index.js

```
const app = require("express")();
const firebase = require('firebase');
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const firebaseConfig = {...};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

const newUser = {
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
    handle: req.body.handle
};

firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
        .then(data => {
            return res.status(201).json({
                message: `User ${newUser.handle} created successfully`
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: err.code
            });
        })

})

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Edit: I'm also adding my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "firebase": "^9.6.9",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.19.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I'm pretty much new on using Firebase with Express.js, I'll gladly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Edit. Added my definition for firebase functions container using express.js exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

Comment: Can you post the package.json file?

Comment: Added to the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have the new [Firebase Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) (`v9.0.0+`) installed and then `const firebase = require("firebase")` import seems to be the issue. If you want to use web SDK, then try refactoring your code as shown below:

```
const app = require("express")();
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const { initializeApp } = require("firebase/app");
const { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth } = require("firebase/auth");

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {...};

  return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      fireAuth,
      newUser.email,
      newUser.password
    )
    .then((data) => {
      return res.status(201).json({
        message: `User ${newUser.handle} created successfully`,
      });
    })
})
```

However you don't need Firebase client SDK to create users in a cloud function. You can use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) for that as shown below:

```
const app = require("express")();
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  const newUser = {...};

  return admin
    .auth()
    .createUser(newUser)
    .then((data) => {
      return res.status(201).json({
        message: `User ${newUser.handle} created successfully`,
      });
    })
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```