# firebase cloud error Failed to load function definition from source

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

unable to  deploy changes to firebase cloud

Action:
"Firebase  Deploy"  in  cmd

results:

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
```

> Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in C:\Users\rushikesh.chaskar\IdeaProjects\todosmanager\node_modules\firebase\package.json

Comment: I found 2 similar stackoverflow threads [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69757557/firebase-functions-error-err-package-path-not-exported-no-exports-main-def) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71536600/firebase-functions-failed-to-deploy). Can you go through it once?

Comment: Just do 'npm install firebase-functions'

Comment: facing similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76942998/functions-codebase-could-not-be-analyzed-successfully-it-may-have-a-syntax-or-r , any help?

Answer (score 65):

Adding to the never ending list of problems. If you get something like the below error, check your imports.

> Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'INTERNAL')

I noticed some outdated Admin SDK instructions had the following:

```js
import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin";
```

Where as the correct import is:

```js
import {initializeApp} from "firebase-admin/app";
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had an error in my code that only surfaced when deploying.

The error I got was `firebase functions "Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')"`

After about an hour of commenting out everything and then uncommenting a chunk at a time I realized my code wasn't deploying to firebase functions because of a line I wrote that included `process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR.toString()`. Apparently when deploying `process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR` is null so trying to call `toString` on it throws an error.

I changed that line to `` `${process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR}` `` and now my firebase functions deploy.

Comment: can confirm this alse worked for me. I had variables that I was referencing in a function file using process.env.variableName and wrapping these in `${process.env.variableName}` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I was able to run `firebase deploy --debug` for verbose output logging which helped me to further narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I soved it by upgrading the firebase-functions dependency

```
yarn add firebase-functions
```

In the functions directory

Answer (score 5):

In my situation, the problem was related to my folder structure. To identify the root cause of the issue, you might be able to analyze the following file.

```
functions/firebase-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I was using `jest` to test my modules. I had files looking like this:

```
potatoes.js
potatoes.test.js
```

So importing doesn't work when I deploy

```js
import {potato} from "./potatoes"
```

I had to do it like this

```js
import {potato} from "./potatoes.js"
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened with @googleapis/androidpublisher when tried to deploy Cloud Functions: `Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module '@googleapis/androidpublisher'`

Interesting thing is VS Code did not detect any issue and it only shows up when I try to deploy. Solution is to run the command and install the npm package:

```
npm install @googleapis/androidpublisher
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened when I run `firebase emulators:start`
I am using typescript and an `npm start` in the functions folder plus the `firebase emulators:start` worked for me.

Edit: you could just run `npm run serve` or `yarn serve` that does both

Answer (score 1):

For this error:

**Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**

cd to the functions folder (you're probably already here) and add "type": "module" in the package.json file after the "description" line. This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had little bit different error, but Google search still shows this thread first.

**My error:**

> Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError:
> Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a
> syntax or runtime error

**Solution:**
Change how you are importing things. My working example (I am using Typescript inside my index.ts functions):

```
import { auth, pubsub, firestore, https, Change, EventContext } from 'firebase-functions'
import { onCall } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https'
import { info } from 'firebase-functions/logger'
import { firestore, messaging } from 'firebase-admin'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'
```

I "migrated" from `require` because it didn't include types, **but it could not be 1:1 when rewriting into imports**.

1. I could not import everything as `import functions from 'firebase-functions'` now and I had to destructure the methods
2. I had to import some of methods from sub-directory (like
   `import { onCall } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https'`)

**Before with require that worked:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const { firestore } = require('firebase-admin')
const { info } = require('firebase-functions/logger')
// import functions from 'firebase-functions' // won't work!
// import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin' // won't work!
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue I  upgrade firebase functions by using **npm install --save firebase-functions@latest** in my functions directory

I had been using an outdated version of firebase-functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the problem without running `npm run build` inside `functions` which stands for `tsc` in a `TypeScript` project. After that, an `import` (inside `nuxt.config.js` btw) has been updated which I could see in `functions/lib/index.js`, and pointed to the correct location. Thanks to it, the error was gone.

The full log was `Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module './nuxt.config.js' Require stack: - /mypath/to/my/project_name/functions/lib/index.js`

Answer (score 0):

I am using typescript and msssql.

What I did, it was to delete the folder lib.

and run the build command again.

I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where my custom error was being thrown, preventing deployment. So it just read:

> Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error:

I was being preemptive and manually checking if my stored API key was present. It was undefined, and I thought something was wrong with my secrets setup, but I guess it just couldn't be deployed with that error check in place... We'll just have to be careful not to try and use it without all the environment variables set.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it turns out I didnot return at the end of the function. Added return true and error went away!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue. To resolve this issue I upgraded firebase functions using this command :npm install --save firebase-functions@latest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the problem was a TypeScript `enum` which I turned into an array to use in my code. Apparently, `firebase-functions` doesn't like that.

I ended up defining the array directly in my code without using the `enum` from my type definitions.

Comment: +1 this sounds weird but I also experienced something similar. Replacing the enum with an enum-type fixed the issue. e.g. `export type foo = "foo" | "bar"`

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I forgot to include the subfolder path in the configuration file.

Code(index.ts):

```
exports.my_group = require('./subfolder/parser')
```

Error:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error: Cannot find module './subfolder/parser'
```

Solution was to change

```
"include": [
  "src"
]
```

to

```
"include": [
  "src", "src/**/*"
 ]
```

in tsconfig.json file.