# Firebase functions keeps throwing undefined error when using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the base typescript install of `firebase init functions`. My project keeps throwing the following error:

```
> npm run build:watch | firebase emulators:start --only functions

i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, firestore, database, hosting, pubsub, storage, eventarc
⚠  Your requested "node" version "16" doesn't match your global version "18". Using node@18 from host.
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/Users/petertoth/Documents/AntlerSlackBotFE/firebase/functions" for Cloud Functions...
⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'INTERNAL')
```

Env:

local:

```
% firebase -V: 11.9.0
% tsc -V: Version 4.8.3
% node --version: v18.7.0
% npm --version: 8.15.0
```

project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.23.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. `firebase init functions`
2. copy and pasta the following into `index.ts`, the actual values of `firebaseConfig` do not matter:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "no",
    authDomain: "Iamnot.myjazz.com",
    projectId: "heloogroot",
    storageBucket: "hello.bello.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123456789123",
    appId: "1:64646546:web:123456789123",
    measurementId: "G-JANDSJANS5"
  };


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const fn = functions.region('europe-west1')
const db = getFirestore()


export const healthCheckDB = fn.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

    const result = (await db.doc('doesnmatter').get()).data()
    response.send(result)
});
```

3. run `npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions`

Comment: Update: I downgraded to `node@16`, issue still persists

Comment: The `db` is a Firestore instance and then you are trying to get `db.doc('doesnmatter')`. This is not specifying a collection name? or if `doesnmatter` is a collection then it should be in `collection()`... so I doubt it actually _matters_ just in case the value you are passing might be undefined. Please share the complete code so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: This answer suggests checking imports:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72225579/firebase-cloud-error-failed-to-load-function-definition-from-source

Can you try navigating to functions `cd .../functions` and then `npm install` ?

Comment: I did install all the dependencies. This is on a base firebase install.

Comment: What is the output and currently selected project when you run `firebase projects:list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of trial and error, I decided to reinstall homebrew and all of its packages. After reinstall and upgrade to the latest version. That solved it, though now I will never know what the *real* issue was.