# facing this issue Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: User code failed to load. Cannot determine backend specification

using node v 18.13.0
please help

tried this : [firebase cloud error Failed to load function definition from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72225579/firebase-cloud-error-failed-to-load-function-definition-from-source)
solutions

Comment: are you on windows or mac?

what command are you doing to start firebase?

What is the full stack trace of errors?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 i used this command
npm install -g firebase-tools npm install -g firebase-tools
used this command:
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions

Comment: Can you please add the `--debug` flag to your `firebase emulators:start` command and see if the debug output has a more detailed error message?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/5931 and an associated change in the firebase-functions (Node) SDK will cause the CLI to start printing errors to the console to improve the debugging experience.